# Vim: How do I see whether a command is switched on?

Tags: vim

I want to implement a function that cycles through setting the line numbers.

I'm having trouble evaluating the state of the number command. For instance I have tried:

```
function! CycleNumbers()
    if exists(":number")
        set nonumber
    elseif exists(":nonumber")
        set number
    endif
endfunction
```

Is there a way to test for number being off? Something like number==off?

Thank you for your help

Comment: why you need check the `:number` command to set line number? they are different things. do you want to toggle line number option?

Comment: I want to toggle whether or not the line numbers show. I know I can just say invnumber. But I want the cycle to be more complex so i need to be able to check the status of the line number display. 
I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Beware! Relative numbering and absolute numbering can BOTH be set in recent versions of Vim, which shows the absolute line at the cursor, and relative numbers everywhere else. Thus you have 4 conditions to check for a full cycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not check the option value? something like :

```
let &number = &number? 0: 1
```

or simply as you said in comment, `set nu!`

to get the information, if line number is shown, read `&number` variable. if it's `1` the number is currently showing. `0`, not.

something like:

```
if &number
   "showing
else
   "not showing
endif
```

fill your logic codes there.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can toggle an option with the exclamation mark (on the command line):

```
:set number!
```

See also `:help set-!`

If you insist on having a function, then you want something like

```
fu! CycleNumbers()

    set number!

endfu
```

**Edit**

If you want to query the current value of the option, you use the `&option` syntax:

```
if &number == 0
   ... 
else
   ...
endif
```

Comment: Thank you, it was more about querying than toggleing. I want to switch from no line numbers -> line numbers -> relative line numbers